# Event for required attributes in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I really can't explain this one properly, so here's a screenshot:
[image]

How do I capture the event when this red highlight appears around an email field on firefox. So that I could perform something. The code below is a just a pseudo code mixed with some formal code:

```
 <script src="jq.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){

        $('#btn_yo').click(function(){
            $('input').each(function(index){
                if($(this:required == 'true'){
                    //do something
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  required/>
    <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn_yo" value="submit"/>
```

the email attribute only accepts email attributes, and when you input something else, its automatically highlighted with red border. How do I go about capturing that event so that I could do a custom action instead of the red-highlight which is the default.

Comment: When does the `red-highlight` appear? is it `onFocus`? `onTextChanged`? or something else?

Comment: the email attribute only accepts email attributes, and when you input something else, its automatically highlighted with red border. How do I go about capturing that event so that I could do a custom action instead of the red-highlight which is the default.

Comment: Does the red highlight appear because the data entered in invalid?

Comment: Is this what you are shooting for:  http://jsfiddle.net/CJ5Zc/

Comment: What I guess its doing is, `onTextChanging/onTextChanged` its checking the text in the `textBox` to match some kind of a `regex` and thus highlight it(if the text is not valid).

Try capturing the `textChanged` event of the `textBox`

Comment: Are you just interested in removing the Firefox default red glow, or do you **need** to do something else as well?

Comment: @zack the human: I just want to perform a validation. Since no matter what the state of the input fields. Tha ajax function still executes in the script that I'm working with.

Comment: Ah, ok. Just for reference, you can remove the red glow in Firefox by using a CSS rule like this: `input:invalid { -moz-box-shadow: none; }`. I don't recommend it since it's really a feature, but if you need to, you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think probably what you want to use is [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/), such that when the user leaves a given input field, you can perform validation of that field and flag it as invalid if needed.  For instance:

```
$("input").blur(function(evt) {
    if (this.required && this.value == "") {
        alert(this.name + " is a required field!");
        $(this).addClass("error");
        this.focus();
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

Which gives you something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/CJ5Zc/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mail').focus(function(){

    alert('focused');
});
```